# Why is etc. added at the end of a \vbox, and what does it mean?

Tags: boxes, plain-tex

A short sample code

```
% pdfTeX
\newbox\thbx
\setbox\thbx\hbox{abc}
\newbox\tvbx
\setbox\tvbx\vbox{\unhbox\thbx}
\showbox\tvbx
\bye
```

would output

```
\thbx=\box16
\tvbx=\box17
> \box17=
\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 434.47717fil
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
..\tenrm a
..\tenrm b
..\kern0.27779
..\tenrm c
..etc.
```

What does the last line of the output (`etc.`) mean, and why is it put there by TeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `\showboxbreadth=5`, i.e. after TeX showed the first five elements of the list it will write `etc.` to indicate that there are more.

There is another parameter which influences the output of `\showbox` and that is `\showboxdepth` (default `3`) which is the level of nesting that TeX descends down into.  If the depth has been exceeded this is denoted by `[]`.

See also this excerpt from the TeXbook:

```
\danger When \TeX\ displays a box as part of diagnostic output, the amount
of data is controlled by two parameters called ^|\showboxbreadth| and
^|\showboxdepth|. The first of these, which plain \TeX\ sets equal to~5,
tells the maximum number of items shown per level; the second, which plain
\TeX\ sets to~3, tells the deepest level. For example, a small box
whose full contents are ^^{internal box format} ^^{symbolic box format}
\begintt
\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x21.0, glue set 0.5
.\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x5.0
..\tenrm g
.\glue 5.0 plus 2.0
.\tenrm || (ligature ---)
\endtt
will be abbreviated as follows when |\showboxbreadth=1| and |\showboxdepth=1|:
^^{ligature} ^^{em-dash}
\begintt
\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x21.0, glue set 0.5
.\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x5.0 []
.etc.
\endtt
And if you set |\showboxdepth=0|, you get only the top level:
\begintt
\hbox(4.30554+1.94444)x21.0, glue set 0.5 []
\endtt
(Notice how `^|[]|' and `^|etc.|'~indicate that the data has been
truncated.)
```